# How to integrate Git with other native issue tracker?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I developed a native issue tracker system that user can create, assign and follow issues status.

For now i need to integrate each git commit special messages like `#{issue id}` OR `Fixes #{issue id}`, etc..., with my own custom issue tacker.

I mean if user write commit and push a change, if commit message contain special characters like `#{issue id}` or special words like `Fixes #{issue id}` must be link to my own issue tracker system.

Also i need change issues status on my custom issue tracker and i need a direct clickable link to call and change issue status.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue tracker has to have an API. On the git side you need a [post-update hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) that parses every commit message, extracts issue IDs and calls appropriate actions using issue tracker's API.

Comment: Wow, It's true, Good solution, Thanks.